# Use Samba AD DC as Password Backend for Samba PDC

Tags: active-directory, samba, smb, pdc, samba-dc

Experts

I've got the following situation:

- Old Samba-server `data.company.com` Version 4.6.7
- Configured as a PDC with `workgroup = COMPANY` for a population of Windows hosts with the following configuration:

```
[global]
        workgroup = COMPANY
        server string = COMPANY Samba Server
        netbios name = SMBMASTER
        unix extensions = no
        max open files = 200000
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        #log level = 9
        ntlm auth = Yes
        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        domain master = yes
        domain logons = yes
        logon path =
        logon script = logon.bat
        logon drive = U:
        local master = yes
        wins support = yes
```

- New Samba-server `dc1.company.com` Version 4.17.4
- Configured as an AD DC with `workgroup = COMPANY-NEW` the following configuration:

```
[global]
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        netbios name = DC1
        realm = COMPANY-NEW.COMPANY.INTERNAL
        server role = active directory domain controller
        workgroup = COMPANY-NEW
        log level = 2
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
        min protocol = SMB2
        ntlm auth = yes
        ldap server require strong auth = no

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/company-new.company.internal/scripts
        read only = No
```

Machines can join fine to both domains, `COMPANY` and `COMPANY-NEW` and, once joined, update their passwords (with Ctrl+Alt+Del in Windows) on the respective domain.

What I would like to achieve is for the old server to use the new server for authentication of the users (as a password backend) so users don't have two passwords. This way, I could slowly migrate the population from the old domain to the new and no matter where a user changes their password, they would implicitly change it for both domains.

Since I cannot join the old server `data.company.com` to the new server `dc1.company.com` because they have different domain names, I tried out setting the LDAP-server of the new server as a passdb backend for the old one as follows:

```
[global]
        workgroup = COMPANY
        server string = COMPANY Samba Server
        netbios name = SMBMASTER
        unix extensions = no
        max open files = 200000
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        #log level = 9
        ntlm auth = Yes
        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        domain master = yes
        domain logons = yes
        logon path =
        logon script = logon.bat
        logon drive = U:
        local master = yes
        wins support = yes
        passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://dc1.company.com
        ldapsam:editposix = yes
        ldapsam:trusted = yes
        ldap admin dn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        ldap suffix = dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
        ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
        ldap user suffix = ou=Users
        ldap ssl = off
        idmap config * : backend = autorid
        idmap config * : range = 10000-24999999
        idmap config COMPANY: backend = ldap
        idmap config COMPANY: range = 10000-19999
        idmap config COMPANY: ldap_base_dn = ou=idmap,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        idmap config COMPANY: ldap_user_dn = cn=admin,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        map untrusted to domain = yes
        ldap delete dn = yes
        ldap password sync = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
```

With this change however, my old server won't start anymore and give me the following message in the logs:

```
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.778601,  3] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1743(main)
  Becoming a daemon.
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.781838,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:161(make_pdb_method_name)
  No builtin backend found, trying to load plugin
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.786133,  2] ../lib/util/modules.c:196(do_smb_load_module)
  Module 'ldapsam' loaded
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.786281,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:280(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Searching for:[(&(objectClass=sambaDomain)(sambaDomainName=COMPANY))]
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.800342,  2] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:794(smbldap_open_connection)
  smbldap_open_connection: connection opened
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.853302,  3] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1013(smbldap_connect_system)
  ldap_connect_system: successful connection to the LDAP server
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.853352,  4] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1092(smbldap_open)
  The LDAP server is successfully connected
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.895873,  3] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:305(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Got no domain info entries for domain
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.934623,  3] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:166(add_new_domain_info)
  add_new_domain_info: Adding new domain
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936770,  1] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:236(add_new_domain_info)
  add_new_domain_info: failed to add domain dn= sambaDomainName=COMPANY,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal with: No such attribute
        0000200A: objectclass sambaDomain is not a valid objectClass in schema
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936814,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:313(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for COMPANY failed with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936896,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:6540(pdb_ldapsam_init_common)
  pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936937,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:180(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://dc1.company.com did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
```

- Could somebody decipher this for me?
- I my idea even remotely going into the right direction for what I'm trying to achieve?
- If so, where is the mistake in my configuration?
- If not, what would be the right approach?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm going bonkers over this. If you need more details about my setup or higher log level outputs I'm happy to provide you with them.